# regex to validate a username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to validate a username with these parameters: "it may only contain alphanumeric characters or dashes and cannot begin with a dash and must have a length between 2-20 characters"

this is my attempt, but it's not quite right

```
/^[a-z0-9]+([a-z0-9-]+[a-z0-9])?$/i
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/^[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]{1,19}$/i
```

`[^-]` allows all sorts of non alphanumeric characters.

Comment: `/\A[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]{1,19}\Z/i`
`\A` and `\Z` match whole input, not single line, as `^` and `$` - above regexp would allow input like:
`some spoofed\nusername`